# Jquery terminal text formatting syntax, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, css, syntax, text-formatting, jquery-terminal

I am using the [jquery terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php) and it is working great. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out the correct syntax that will format my string.

The example says

```
echo([string|function], [options]) — display string on terminal — (additionally if you can call this function with a function as argument it will call that function and print the result, this function will be called every time you resize the terminal or browser). There are three options raw — it will allow to display raw html, finalize — which is callback function with one argument the div container and flush — default is true, if it's false it will not print echo text to terminal until you call flush method. 

You can also use basic text formating using syntax as folow: 

[[guib;<COLOR>;<BACKGROUND>]some text] will display some text:

[[ — open formating
u — underline
s — strike
o — overline
i — italic
b — bold
g — glow (using css text-shadow)
; — separator
color — color of text (hex, short hex or html name of the color)
; — separator
color — background color (hex, short hex or html name of the color)
; — separator [optional]
class — class adeed to format span element [optional]
] — end of format specification
text — text that will be formated (most of the time for internal use, when you format text that's wrap in more then one line you'll get full text in data-text attribute)
] — end of formating
```

Ok... So I've tried stuff like this

```
terminal.echo(["s"], myText);
```

and this

```
terminal.echo("[[s]" + myText + "]");
```

and this

```
terminal.echo([["s"], myText]);
```

and several others.

This may be a dumb/easy question, but I'm truly stumped. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: At first glance your second attempt should work, but the documentation does not say `<COLOR>` and `<BACKGROUND>` are optional. Maybe you should specify them.

Comment: unfortunately , with the second attempt, I just see "[[s" etc... as a part of the outputed text

Comment: Yup, that's why I suggested you specify `<COLOR>` and `<BACKGROUND>`. The documentation only says the class is optional, so it looks the other parameters are mandatory.

Comment: that did it. write this as an answer and I'll give you the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from Frédéric Hamidi, I needed to include COLOR and BACKGROUND, they were not optional.

Comment: You can skip them but semicolons are required. for instance `[[s;;]sometext]`

Comment: could you please post an example... I have the same problem but still don't understand how to use it...